# RegEx to rewrite folder structure of varying length and file name to string

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

This is the code I'm using, developed with the help of @anubhava to rewrite a path generated by a CGI script to redirect the path from the location of my jpg image files to another folder that contains watermarked image files in the same folder structure organization as the originals, but exclude files that begin with `tn_` or `AM` (plus `_category_image.jpg`):

```
RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_)[^.]+\.jpg)$ /ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2 [L,R=302,NC]
```

The original path of:

```
/ImageFolio4_files/1/Casual_Portraits/abc123_789-xyz.jpg
```

And the above RegEx works to properly generate this output:

```
/ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~Casual_Portraits~abc123_789-xyz.jpg
```

My CHALLENGE: I need to accommodate a multi-folder structure up to three folders deep underneath the `ImageFolio4_files/1/` structure. The current code doesn't accomodate that.  I also need to exclude any files named `_category_image.jpg` which occurs at each of the folder levels beneath `ImageFolio4_files/1/` (these files are unique small display icons that appear next to the category names)

I really have no idea how to accomodate the multi-folder structure so your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, change

```
([^/]+)/     to     (([^/]+)/)+
```

in your expression. 
Second, change

```
(?!AM|tn_)    to    (?!AM|tn_|_category_image.jpg)
```

You can use the the negative lookahead (?!) for the whole filename as well, it doesn't eat up characters, just checks if the regex "AM|tn_|_category_image.jpg" matches at the actual position.